# how to get multiple character in one input in C

Tags: c, stdio

I'm new to C programming so i'm trying to write a piece of code where i need to take ip address in hexadecimal but i couldn't figure out how to do. as far as i know i can't get multiple input with **char** but with **int** when user enters 'A' for example it turns out huge number. 
for decimal inputs i wrote something like this

```
int main(){
    int IP_1,IP_2,IP_3,IP_4;
    printf("Enter the IP address:\n");
    scanf("%d.%d.%d.%d",&IP_1,&IP_2,&IP_3,&IP_4);
```

i used 4 variables because later i will use those numbers for conversion.

edit: sorry for not adding this i can't use either hexadecimal %x or arrays/strings

Comment: Use `%x` to take input in hex, `%d` is for decimal input.

Comment: But the variable needs to be `unsigned int` when you do this.

Comment: Who writes IPv4 addresses in hex? IPv4 is usually decimal, IPv6 is hex.

Comment: The notation you're looking at is 'dotted decimal', not hexadecimal.  You have to check the return value from `scanf()` — ensure that it is 4 — before using the results.  If there's a letter in the data, other than after some digits for the fourth number, then you'll get a return value less than 4 (0..3, or EOF if there's no data left at all after skipping white space).

Comment: %hhu can be used to process the value as an unsigned char

Comment: Why would you not be allowed to use %x? Is this homework or a coding challenge that you need to complete?

Comment: @ChrisTaylor yep and i'm not allowed to use those

Comment: @jongspiration ok, but are you allowed to create your own functions ?

Comment: @Christophe ah i forgot those, nope i can't use functions either i have to do all thing in only body function. i know it sounds ridiculous and in the and this code will be hundreds lines long but...

Comment: @xing it's expected to input in formal format: ***.***.***.***  (including dots) if you have something bigger than 255(FF) it has to say the input is invalid and retake it. and i have to use the input for converting it to binary.

Comment: @xing 00010001 since its hexadecimal 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What's the problem ?

The huge value when you enter a letter is because `scanf()` doesn't recognize the letter as valid input for an int, and stops reading, leaving the remaining variables unassigned.

### How to solve it ?

First you should check if you've read as many variables as you've expected:

```
if (scanf("%d.%d.%d.%d",&IP_1,&IP_2,&IP_3,&IP_4)<4) {
    printf ("Error:  invalid format !\n"); 
}
```

You may then want to read the integer in hexadecimal format:

```
scanf("%x.%x.%x.%x",&IP_1,&IP_2,&IP_3,&IP_4);
```

You'll find more about the input formatting with [`scanf()` here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)

**Important remark:** The convention for an IPv4 address, is to use dots to separate decimal components.  For an hexadecimal notation,  the digits are in principle consecutive, each component being 2 digits.

#### Edit

If you're not allowed to use `%x`, nor arrays, nor strings, then you can only input hex digits as char.  Assuming that every hex part is entered on 2 digits,  you may then have to input 8 chars:

```
char c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8; 
scanf("%c%c.%c%c.%c%c.%c%c",&c1, &c2, &c3, &c4, &c5, &c6, &c7,&c8);
// are you sure you have to enter the dots ?
```

To convert two hex chars into an int, without using strings and arrays you can do:

```
if (c1>='A' && c1<='F') 
    IP_1 = c1-'A'; 
else if (c1>='0' && c1<='9') 
    IP_1 = c1-'0';
else 
    IP_1 = 0;   // OUCH! THIS IS AN ERROR

IP_1 = IP_1 *16; 
if (c2>='A' && c2<='F') 
    IP_1 = IP_1 + c2-'A'; 
else if (c2>='0' && c2<='9') 
    IP_1 = IP_1 + c2-'0';
else 
    IP_1 = 0;   // OUCH! THIS IS AGAIN AN ERROR
```

I let as an exercise for you to add the case where the digits are lower case.  I let you complete for all the characters, since you are not allowed to create functions.

#### FInal remark

Giving exercises that force students to massacre worldwide accepted IP address conventions, and then forcing students to copy paste code seems to me obvious signs of a completely incompetent teacher.

In your interest, you should not be as transparent and open as I am here.  However, I feel obliged to warn you:  go for some nice tutorials on the web.  Or buy a K&R and do all the exercices contained therein.  You'll learn real skills, instead of taking bad habits.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{        
    unsigned int IP_1,IP_2,IP_3,IP_4; 

    printf("Enter the IP address:\n");
    scanf("%x %x %x %x",&IP_1,&IP_2,&IP_3,&IP_4); //storing in Hex format

    printf("%x %x %x %x",IP_1,IP_2,IP_3,IP_4); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to read a string and then use the functions that already exist for converting string to IP (namely, `inet_aton()`).
Also, I would avoid `scanf` for strings, is insecure.

See https://ideone.com/aO9Nll for a live demo and the code.

Comment: Please put the code in the answer so as to make it self-contained. ideone.com is a 3rd party resource, giving your answer a shelf-life dependent upon how long that resource keeps the paste stored