# Converting hexadecimal char IP to binary

Tags: c

I asked a question few days ago and it helped me quite a bit but yet I have a question again. What I don't get is when I get hexadecimal input as scanf("%c%c.%c%c.%c%c.%c%c%c") how do I convert this to binary as it is. What I'm trying to say is let's say I get input as 00.11.10.FF how do I convert it to 00000000.00010001.00010000.11111111 and print it like this.

I will be glad if you help me.

Comment: Hex -> binary is extremely simple.  Every hex digit turns into exactly 4 binary bits.

Comment: So I basically take every variable and convert them. But that would require tons of if statements right?

Comment: First you understand when you are reading `"%c%c...."` you are reading ASCII characters and not numbers, so you first must convert between the ASCII character `[0-9A-F]` to the corresponding *numeric value*. Once you have the decimal representation -- the binary is already what is stored in memory. Alternatively, you can write a *lookup-table* to go directly from ASCII to binary representation of that character -- up to you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get multiple character in one input in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55201616/how-to-get-multiple-character-in-one-input-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

If you are still having problems, as explained in the comments, unless you want to create a lookup-table (which is a fine way to go), your first task is to convert the ASCII characters `"00.11.10.FF"` into actual numeric values of `0x0, 0x11, 0x10 & 0xff`. There are a number of ways to do this, but if you are reading with `scanf`, you may as well let `scanf` do it for you by reading with the `"%x"` format specifier which will accept the hex-characters and perform the conversion.

For example, to read each of the quads into an array of `unsigned` values named `hex`, you could do:

```
#define QUAD  4u    /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
...
    unsigned hex[QUAD] = {0};   /* let's input the values as numbers */
    ...
    if (scanf ("%x.%x.%x.%x", &hex[0], &hex[1], &hex[2], &hex[3]) != 4) {
        fputs ("error: invalid input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
```

(**note:** you could declare `hex` as `unsigned char` and save the additional bytes, but then you would want to limit the value read by `scanf` using the `hh` *type-modifier*, e.g. `"%hhx"`, but that prefix isn't supported on older versions of VS, so in this case a simple `unsigned` is used instead)

With the hex-characters converted to numeric values, all that remains is outputting the binary-representation of each (i.e. the value that is already stored in memory). To do so, you can simply loop and shift, checking whether the bit is a `0` or `1` and outputting the corresponding character `'0'` or `'1'`.

Additionally, since a simple loop and shift will only output until there are no more `1's` bits left, you will want to set the number of bits to display to make sure you get a full 8-per-byte by looping that number of times. A handy function to write the information to `stdout` for the number of bits requested can be:

```
/** binary representation of 'v' padded to 'sz' bits.
 *  the padding amount is limited to the number of
 *  bits in 'v'. valid range: 1 - sizeof v * CHAR_BIT.
 */
void binprnpad (const unsigned long v, size_t sz)
{
    if (!sz) { fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid sz.\n"); return; }
    if (!v)  { while (sz--) putchar ('0'); return; }

    if (sz > sizeof v * CHAR_BIT)
        sz = sizeof v * CHAR_BIT;

    while (sz--)
        putchar ((v >> sz & 1) ? '1' : '0');
}
```

(`CHAR_BIT` is a macro representing the number of bits-per-byte and is found in `limits.h`)

Putting it altogether, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define QUAD  4u    /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define QBITS 8u

/** binary representation of 'v' padded to 'sz' bits.
 *  the padding amount is limited to the number of
 *  bits in 'v'. valid range: 0 - sizeof v * CHAR_BIT.
 */
void binprnpad (const unsigned long v, size_t sz)
{
    if (!sz) { fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid sz.\n"); return; }
    if (!v)  { while (sz--) putchar ('0'); return; }

    if (sz > sizeof v * CHAR_BIT)
        sz = sizeof v * CHAR_BIT;

    while (sz--)
        putchar ((v >> sz & 1) ? '1' : '0');
}

int main (void) {

    unsigned hex[QUAD] = {0};   /* let's input the values as numbers */

    fputs ("enter hex IP: ", stdout);   /* read/validate input */
    if (scanf ("%x.%x.%x.%x", &hex[0], &hex[1], &hex[2], &hex[3]) != 4) {
        fputs ("error: invalid input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < QUAD; i++) {   /* loop over each quad */
        if (i)                      /* if not zero output the '.' */
            putchar ('.');
        binprnpad (hex[i], QBITS);  /* output the 8-bits per quad */
    }
    putchar ('\n');     /* tidy up with newline */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/hexip2bin
enter hex IP: 00.11.10.FF
00000000.00010001.00010000.11111111
```

**Reading Only Characters -- The Lookup Table Approach**

If you can only read characters and cannot read into an array or string, then the simplest approach is to simply read a characters and lookup what its binary representation would be from a simply table that holds the binary representations for `0 - 15` (or `[0-9A-F]` in other words).

The lookup table can be a simple global, e.g.

```
/* lookup table for hex byte binary representations */
char *lookup[] = {  "0000", "0001", "0010", "0011", 
                    "0100", "0101", "0110", "0111", 
                    "1000", "1001", "1010", "1011",
                    "1100", "1101", "1110", "1111"  };
```

The scheme is then straight forward, read a character from the user, if the character `c` is `0-9`, just output `lookup[c - '0']` (where `c - '0'` results in the number `0-9` See: [ASCIITable.com](http://www.asciitable.com/)). If the character `c` is `[A-F]` then output `lookup[c - '7']` (which subtracts the ASCII character value of `'7'` to index `10-15` in the lookup table). Otherwise, if the character is a `'.'`, just output it unchanged.

To protect against someone entering `"00.11.10.ff"`, just convert all characters read to uppper-case with `toupper()` provided in `ctype.h` (or clear the 6th bit in all `[a-f]` manually).

That's as simple as it gets. You don't even need `scanf`, just `getchar();`, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define QBYTES 8u   /* if you need a constant, #define one */

/* lookup table for hex byte binary representations */
char *lookup[] = {  "0000", "0001", "0010", "0011", 
                    "0100", "0101", "0110", "0111", 
                    "1000", "1001", "1010", "1011",
                    "1100", "1101", "1110", "1111"  };
int main (void) {

    unsigned ndx = 0;   /* index of the hex byte read */

    fputs ("enter hex IP: ", stdout);   /* read/validate input */

    while (ndx < QBYTES) {  /* read until 8 hex bytes read */
        unsigned char c = toupper(getchar());   /* read char as upper-case */
        if (isdigit (c)) {                      /* if [0-9] */
            fputs (lookup[c - '0'], stdout);
            ndx++;  /* increment index */
        }
        else if (isxdigit (c)) {                /* if [A-F] */
            fputs (lookup[c - '7'], stdout);
            ndx++;
        }
        else if (c == '.')                      /* if '.' */
            putchar (c);
        else {      /* handle character not [0-9A-F.] */
            fputs ("(error: invalid character input)\n", stderr);
            break;
        }
    }
    putchar ('\n');     /* tidy up with newline */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/hexip2bin
enter hex IP: 00.11.10.FF
00000000.00010001.00010000.11111111
```

lower-case hex example:

```
$ ./bin/hexip2bin
enter hex IP: 00.11.10.ff
00000000.00010001.00010000.11111111
```

**Read A `char` Output A Nibble**

And, of course, you can always mix and match between the methods. If you can't use a *lookup-table*, then just get the numeric value of the character and write the 4-bits representing that hex value as output, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define QUAD  4u    /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define QBYTES 8u

/** binary representation of 'v' padded to 'sz' bits.
 *  the padding amount is limited to the number of
 *  bits in 'v'. valid range: 1 - sizeof v * CHAR_BIT.
 */
void binprnpad (const unsigned long v, size_t sz)
{
    if (!sz) { fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid sz.\n"); return; }
    if (!v)  { while (sz--) putchar ('0'); return; }

    if (sz > sizeof v * CHAR_BIT)
        sz = sizeof v * CHAR_BIT;

    while (sz--)
        putchar ((v >> sz & 1) ? '1' : '0');
}

int main (void) {

    unsigned ndx = 0;   /* index of the hex byte read */

    fputs ("enter hex IP: ", stdout);   /* read/validate input */

    while (ndx < QBYTES) {  /* read until 8 hex bytes read */
        unsigned char c = toupper(getchar());   /* read char as upper-case */
        if (isdigit (c)) {                      /* if [0-9] */
            binprnpad (c - '0', QUAD);
            ndx++;
        }
        else if (isxdigit (c)) {                /* if [A-F] */
            binprnpad (c - '7', QUAD);
            ndx++;
        }
        else if (c == '.')                      /* if '.' */
            putchar (c);
        else {      /* handle character not [0-9A-F.] */
            fputs ("(error: invalid character input)\n", stderr);
            break;
        }
    }
    putchar ('\n');     /* tidy up with newline */

    return 0;
}
```

(output is the same)

Just another way of skinning the same cat. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer! But the thing is I don't quite know them as we didn't learn them yet. The reason I am using %c to take input is because the instructor said we can't use %x, arrays to store values and strings as I said because we didn't learn them yet. This is my first year in computer engineering and this is for an assignment of c programming language. I apologize, should've wrote it in the main post.

Comment: Ok, I can help you out there, I'll drop an addition. (and you should slap your professor for the additional needless work `:)`

Comment: Thank you for explaining in such detail. This is going to be really helpful for me. Although I can't use that code fully I will modify it a bit to not break the rules. The professor says this will be helpful in the future but I really can't see myself working on a project and not using %x. Anyway thanks again!