# How do I print 1 bit in C (not only the least significant bit)?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I am working on a program that sends TCP header (a simulation of the 3-handshaking). I have a variable and this variable contains the data offset (3 bits), reserved (4 bits), and the 9 flags (9 bits). I am using bitwise operations to set the bits. The question is how can I print each of those bits?

1. Suppose I store the data offset starting on 2 to 4 (left to right): ex. 0111000000000000

How can I print the 3 bits? Variable:

```
u_int16_t reserved_ofs_flags;
```

I found this question similar, but the answer only works for the least significant: [How do I print one bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349931/how-do-i-print-one-bit)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To extract `N` bits from an `unsigned` value starting at position `P`, counting from `0` for the least significant bit, you can use this expression:

```
unsigned x = (value >> P) & ((1U << (N - 1) << 1) - 1);
```

Notes:

- numbering the bits from *left to right* is a confusing convention. In software, the preferred numbering method is from the least significant bit (number 0) to the most significant bit (number 15 in your example).
- If `N` is a compile time constant, the expression `((1U << (N - 1) << 1) - 1)` is evaluated at compile time.
- The expression assumes that `N` is at least `1` and at most the number of bits in the `unsigned` type.
- A simpler expression `((1U << N) - 1)` has undefined behavior if `N` is the number of bits in the `unsigned` type.
- For your example `P` is `12` and `N` is `3` so you can write: `unsigned x = (value >> 12) & 7;`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [bitwise operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C) to get the bits you want.

For instance:

```c
unsigned int a = 22;           // 10110 in binary
printf("%d\n", a & 1);         // get the bit in the 1's place (0)
printf("%d\n", (a >> 1) & 1);  // get the bit in the 2's place (1)
printf("%d\n", (a >> 2) & 1);  // get the bit in the 4's place (1)
printf("%d\n", (a >> 3) & 1);  // get the bit in the 8's place (0)
printf("%d\n", (a >> 4) & 1);  // get the bit in the 16's place (1)

// 3 in decimal is 11 in binary
printf("%d\n", a & 3);         // get the bits in the 1's and the 2's places
                               // (2 in decimal, 10 in binary)
printf("%d\n", (a >> 1) & 3);  // get the bits in the 2's and the 4's places
                               // (3 in decimal, 11 in binary)
```

Comment: Amazing answer!

Comment: Technically, since the type of `a` is `unsigned`, the `printf` formats should be `%u` instead of `%d`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, and you want to be able to extract the value of the `N` number of bits (from `1` to `sizeof(type) * CHAR_BIT`) beginning at position `P` (from `0` to `sizeof(type) * CHAR_BIT - 1`) then you can extract that subset of bits with:

```c
/** extract N bits from value starting at position P, 
 *  counting from 0 for the least significant bit
 */
unsigned nbitsatp (unsigned value, unsigned N, unsigned P)
{
  /* mask is N 1's bits */
  unsigned mask = ~0u >> ((sizeof mask * CHAR_BIT) - N); 
  
  return (value >> (P - N + 1)) & mask;
}
```

(**note:** for 4-byte `unsigned`, `N` ranges from `1` to `32` while `P` is zero-based ranging from `0` to `31`)

Above, the `mask` begins with all bits `1` (`~0u`) and then shifts off the total number of bits minus `N` (leaving `N` 1's bits). The `value` is then shifted by `P - N + 1` so that you `AND` the desired number of bits at position `P` with the corresponding number of 1's bits. Since both are shifted so the values begin at the least significant bit, the result is the value of the `N` bits at position `P`.

This avoids having to hardcode the number and individual bit positions for each range of bits you want.

In your example you want to extract the first 3 bits from `0111000000000000` (`28672`) which would be the 3 bits `N == 3` at positon `P == 15`, the result being `011` (`3`).

**A Short Example**

The example below uses `unsigned` as the type, which so long as it is at least 2-bytes on your hardware will be more than sufficient for `uint16_t` type.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

/** extract N bits from value starting at position P, 
 *  counting from 0 for the least significant bit
 */
unsigned nbitsatp (unsigned value, unsigned N, unsigned P)
{
  /* mask is N 1's bits */
  unsigned mask = ~0u >> ((sizeof mask * CHAR_BIT) - N); 
  
  return (value >> (P - N + 1)) & mask;
}

int main (void) {

  unsigned v, n, p;
  
  fputs ("enter v, n, p : ", stdout);    /* prompt for v, n, p */
  
  /* read/validate positive int value */
  if (scanf ("%u%u%u", &v, &n, &p) != 3) {
    fputs ("error: invalid unsigned integer input.\n", stderr);
    return 1;
  }
  
  /* output result */
  printf ("\nvalue of %u bits at pos %u in %u is : %u\n", 
          n, p, v, nbitsatp (v, n, p));
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Your specific example of wanting the 3 bits beginning a position 15 of `28672`:

```
$ ./bin/nbitsatp
enter v, n, p : 28672 3 15

value of 3 bits at pos 15 in 28672 is : 3
```

Or let's take the first 4 bits at position 15, `0111` (`7`):

```
$  ./bin/nbitsatp
enter v, n, p : 28672 4 15

value of 4 bits at pos 15 in 28672 is : 7
```

Or the first 5-bits beginning at position 15:

```
$ ./bin/nbitsatp
enter v, n, p : 28672 5 15

value of 5 bits at pos 15 in 28672 is : 14
```

Or what about the value for the 9-flags (9 bits, at position 8) which will be all zero in your example:

```
$ ./bin/nbitsatp
enter v, n, p : 28672 9 8

value of 9 bits at pos 8 in 28672 is : 0
```

**Using Pre-Defined Macros To Retrieve Wanted Bits**

A convenient way to use the `nbitsatp()` function to retrieve the bits you are interested in is to `#define` a macro for each group of bits you want to obtain. For example to get the 3-bits for the data offset, the reserved 4-bits and the 9-bit set of flags, you could define three macros that set the number of bits and position allowing you to simply pass the TCP Header value as an argument, e.g.

```c
/* macros for 3-bit offset, 4-bit reserved, 9-bit flags */
#define HDR_OFFSET(TCPHDRVAL) nbitsatp ((TCPHDRVAL), 3, 15)
#define HDR_RESERVED(TCPHDRVAL) nbitsatp ((TCPHDRVAL), 4, 12)
#define HDR_FLAGS(TCPHDRVAL) nbitsatp ((TCPHDRVAL), 9, 8)
```

To obtain the bits you want, just call the macro passing the TCP header value as an argument, e.g.

```c
int main (void) {

  unsigned v;
  
  fputs ("enter TCP hdr value : ", stdout);   /* prompt TCP HDR VAL */
  
  /* read/validate TCP header value */
  if (scanf ("%u", &v) != 1) {
    fputs ("error: invalid unsigned integer input.\n", stderr);
    return 1;
  }
  
  /* output result */
  printf ("\n   data offset bits : %u\n"
          "   reserved bits    : %u\n"
          "   flag bits        : %u\n", 
          HDR_OFFSET (v), HDR_RESERVED (v), HDR_FLAGS (v));
}
```

**Output**

```
$ /bin/nbitsatp_macro
enter TCP hdr value : 28672

   data offset bits : 3
   reserved bits    : 8
   flag bits        : 0
```

If wanted, you can output the padded binary representation for `3` (`011`), `8` (`1000`) and then the flags (`000000000`) in a trivial manner. See [binprnpad() function in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55203442/3422102)